# invoice skip button validasi and go to register payment in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, openerp-8

[image: invoice skip validate]

> i want to create custom button for skip this validate in invoice and
>   register payment, but still validate..

i've tried using this code but not working

```
class SaleOrderTestingView(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    def button_custom(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        print ">>>>>>>>> berhasil bro haha"
        self.invoice_pay_customer(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

To auto-validate a draft invoice, call workflow `invoice_open` after create invoice. try below code:

```
 def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    result=super(account_invoice, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
    self.signal_workflow(cr, uid, [result], 'invoice_open')
    return result
```